# Google Drive Api crashes Excel file

Tags: java, excel, google-drive-api

I am trying to write simple java app which uses Google Drive Api to upload Excel files. I created file with .xlsx extension and create test empty sheet. So I use Google Drive Api and upload this file into my drive. The problem is that after opening this file directly on drive I see some strange chars (as if it crashed)
Code and photo of file:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("src/main/sheets/wb5.xlsx");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving found: to work with .xlsx files you have to change mimeType:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("My");
    String mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    fileMetadata.setMimeType(mimeType);


    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("src/main/sheets/wb5.xlsx");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, filePath);
    File file = driveManager.utils().getDriveService().files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
```